# How to add new font to label in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, fonts

I need to use a pixel font "8bitoperator_jve" in label in WPF from https://ru.fonts2u.com/8bitoperator-jve-regular.%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82. I've downloaded .ttf file with font and put it to Resources, set 'Resource' in Build Action and tried the following code:

```
<Label FontFamily="./#8bitoperator_jve" FontSize="100"  Foreground="White"> Check </Label>
```

It wouldn't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use it directly after installation

```
this.label1.FontFamily = new FontFamily("8bitoperator JVE Regular");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting an incorrect font name. You must enter the actual font name, not the filename. Open the font and copy the Font name. Try this:

```
<Label FontFamily="./#8bitoperator JVE" FontSize="100" Foreground="White"> Check </Label>
```

I'm not sure if `./` is correct, if the code above won't work, try to remove this and leave just `#8bitoperator JVE`

Comment: If you install a new font, you just need to enter the name. No ./ needed, The compiler looks into the folders where installed fonts are stored by default, and you just need to enter the name